# Having an issue with Firebase Auth on iOS Null Error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently having a problem with logging into firebase on my iOS app, I recently got a new laptop and decided I would migrate from swift 3 to 4 on there, however I discovered a problem, before I hit the convert everything to swift 4 and got tons of errors, I launched the app still running on Swift 3, but I couldnt seem to log in, I am getting the error showed below.

I then switched back to to my old macbook air that is still got the orignal app and old version of xcode running and tried logging in there as I usually would. However, still getting this error showed below. There is not much context shown as I just get "null" in the localised description? Has anyone been faced with this?

This is just standard email authentication with Firebase

> error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000008466c0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=4 "(null)"

Comment: Do you have the correct domains set on your Firebase Auth? Looks like you are not accesing the auth functionality from a whitelist domain. Go to your console and check if domains allowed match the domain you are using.

Comment: Still no luck Alex, everything looks the same unfortunately. Really not sure what this could be?